# Merging event rows into one row in Bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to combine all events that are written into a bigquery table into one unique row which shows the latest snapshot.

Ex: The rows that come as part of events captures each of the field changes in incremental order

| id | phone | first_name__c | last_name__c | lastmodifieddate | changedfields |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001O1000008Z6M8IAK |  |  |  | 2024-02-19 21:01:31.000000 UTC | [LastModifiedDate,Last_Name__c] |
| 001O1000008Z6M8IAK |  | Rambo1 |  | 2024-02-19 21:01:18.000000 UTC | [LastModifiedDate,First_Name__c] |
| 001O1000008Z6M8IAK |  |  | Rancho2 | 2024-02-19 21:00:40.000000 UTC | [LastModifiedDate,Last_Name__c] |
| 001O1000008Z6M8IAK |  | Rambo | Rancho | 2024-02-19 21:00:18.000000 UTC | [LastModifiedDate,First_Name__c,Last_Name__c] |
| 001O1000008Z6M8IAK | 1228312328 |  |  | 2024-02-19 20:56:10.000000 UTC | [Phone,LastModifiedDate] |
| 001O1000008Z6M8IAK | 1228312321 |  |  | 2024-02-19 20:55:50.000000 UTC | [Phone,LastModifiedDate] |

I am trying to convert into single row snapshot

| id | phone | first_name__c | last_name__c | lastmodifieddate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001O1000008Z6M8IAK | 1228312328 | Rambo1 |  | 2024-02-19 21:01:31.000000 UTC |

Rules:
The changed_field column confirms the value that was modified as part of the event.
The final merged row must be latest snapshot for each column based on changed_field column.
Ex: The last event says last_name__c column value was updated and the value it shows is null/empty. So the final row should show the last_name__c column as empty but not Rancho2

My initial logic was to do something like finding the first value which is not null like so

```
with temp as (select id, 
lastmodifieddate,
FIRST_VALUE(phone ignore nulls) OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY lastmodifieddate desc) AS phone,
FIRST_VALUE(first_name__c ignore nulls) OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY lastmodifieddate desc) AS first_name__c,
FIRST_VALUE(last_name__c ignore nulls) OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY lastmodifieddate desc) AS last_name__c
from `bigquery_table`
where id = '001O1000008Z6M8IAK'
order by lastmodifieddate desc)
select id, phone,first_name__c,last_name__c, row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY lastmodifieddate asc) as row_n
from temp
qualify row_n = 1
```

[image]
I am not sure how to make sure the null value is captured from the last event.
Or if there is any better way to do this

Comment: Please can you update your question with the actual rules that need to be applied. For example, why should last name be null and not Rancho2?

Comment: You'll need to parse the changedFields column to differentiate between value=NULL and valueUnchanged.

Comment: @nickW Because the ChangedFields column (in the newest row) says the last name was changed.

Comment: @NickW updated the question as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH
  columns_dated AS
(
  SELECT
    *,
    CASE WHEN changedFields LIKE '%Phone%'         THEN lastmodifeddate END   AS phone_date,
    CASE WHEN changedFields LIKE '%First_Name__c%' THEN lastmodifeddate END   AS first_date,
    CASE WHEN changedFields LIKE '%Last_Name__c%'  THEN lastmodifeddate END   AS last_date
  FROM
    `bigquery_table`
),
  column_dates_ranked AS
(
  SELECT
    *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
      PARTITION BY id,
          ORDER BY phone_date DESC
    )
      AS phone_rank,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
      PARTITION BY id,
          ORDER BY first_date DESC
    )
      AS first_rank,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
      PARTITION BY id,
          ORDER BY last_date DESC
    )
      AS last_rank
  FROM
    columns_dated
)
SELECT
  id,
  MAX(CASE WHEN phone_rank = 1 THEN phone         END),
  MAX(CASE WHEN first_rank = 1 THEN first_name__c END),
  MAX(CASE WHEN last_rank  = 1 THEN last_name__c  END),
  MAX(lastmodifeddate)
FROM
  column_dates_ranked
GROUP BY
  id
```

Comment: Also, sue / fire / punch whomever designed this data format. It's not suitable for effective database use.

Comment: lol.. That helps Thanks. In order to better the design. I am thinking of differentiating empty value null, from changed_field value 'null'. I mean what if based on the changed field, if the actual changed value is null, use a temporary 'mask_null' value in that column. Then use analytical function like FIRST_VALUE as mentioned in my question. Will that be a little more efficient?

Comment: @Arpit Fill in ***all*** the values (whether or not they change), giving a regular history table. Leaving NULLs saves very little space. Or, have an Entity Atribute Value table (id, column_name, column_new_value, timestamp). Whatever you do, don't have comma delimited strings (arrays are much preferred), and don't use special values to represent "real" NULLs.